# Grouping/stacking rasters from list of path and extract their min values for each group

Tags: r, list, raster

I have a list of rasters path (`rplist` = 912 raster pathe for 912 rasters (19yeras)*(12months)*(4weeks)) as below:

```
  [1] "C:/Users/Eric/Downloads/Results/RMI_2000_02_18.tif"
  [2] "C:/Users/Eric/Downloads/Results/RMI_2000_02_26.tif"
  [3] "C:/Users/Eric/Downloads/Results/RMI_2000_03_05.tif"
  [4] "C:/Users/Eric/Downloads/Results/RMI_2000_03_13.tif"
  [5] "C:/Users/Eric/Downloads/Results/RMI_2000_03_21.tif"
  [...] "......"
  [912] "C:/Users/Eric/Downloads/Results/RMI_2019_03_21.tif"
```

I need to read the rasters group them on monthly basis for each year (e.g. those belonging to RMI_2000_02) and then extract the minimum of each overlaying cell as a seperate raster (ignore NA values if any).

```
################### SETTING UP WORKING DIRECTORY ############################
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))

# list rasters in workin directory
rplist <- list.files(getwd(),full.names = TRUE)
```

From here I dont know what I can do with rs (as above) but shoudl be:

```
1. read rasters using rplist
2. group them by month for each year
3. extract the min raster
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by min raster?

Comment: @Rohit min stands for minimum here. That is a raster formed by extracting minimum values for every cell in a monthly group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a good answer you should provide some example data (not an external file, use data that come with R, or create some with code). What you can do is create a RasterStack `s` and a vector `v` that groups the layers that need to be combined, and then do

```
x <- stackApply(s, v, fun=min, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Now with example data

```
library(raster)
# RasterStack with 12 layers
s <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
s <- stack(s, s*2, s*3, s*4)
# make one layer with only NAs
values(s[[2]]) <- NA

# 12 corresponding dates
d <- paste0("RMI_2000", rep(sprintf("_%02d", 1:3), each=4), "_0", 1:4)
d
# [1] "RMI_2000_01_01" "RMI_2000_01_02" "RMI_2000_01_03" "RMI_2000_01_04" "RMI_2000_02_01" "RMI_2000_02_02" "RMI_2000_02_03" "RMI_2000_02_04" "RMI_2000_03_01" "RMI_2000_03_02" "RMI_2000_03_03" "RMI_2000_03_04"


# transform date into an index (stripping of the label and the week number)
i <- substr(d, 4, 11)
i
#[1] "2000_01" "2000_01" "2000_01" "2000_01" "2000_02" "2000_02" "2000_02" "2000_02" "2000_03" "2000_03" "2000_03" "2000_03"


ss <- stackApply(s, i, min, na.rm=TRUE)
ss
#class       : RasterBrick 
#dimensions  : 77, 101, 7777, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=merc +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#data source : in memory
#names       : index_2000_01, index_2000_02, index_2000_03 
#min values  :             0,             0,             0 
#max values  :           255,           510,           765
```

Comment: It was not easy for me to come up with a reproducible example for this one. I have managed to make my raster stack (s) where the names of rasters are **sort(apply(expand.grid(sprintf("RMI_%04d", 2000:2019),sprintf("_%02d", 1:12),sprintf("_%02d", 1:4)), 1, paste, collapse = "", sep = ""))** Your solution is great but I have a problem in applying it.

Comment: Thanks, I used a reduced version of that

Comment: I confirm that this works well for portion of my data and several other test data but runs forever when I apply it to the whole dataset 4800, 7200, 34560000, 866  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers).

Comment: It will take a while, but not forever

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is as below:

```
# list rasters in workin directory
rplist <- list.files(getwd(),full.names = TRUE)
r_name <- list.files(getwd(),full.names = FALSE)

# 1. read rasters using rplist
mrlist <- lapply(rplist, raster)
names(mrlist) <- r_name

# 2. stack rasters of the same month
tstList <- list()
tstStack <- stack()
i <- 1
for (y in 2000:2019){
  for (m in 1:12){
    # paste0(y,"_",sprintf("%02d", m)) returnes YEAR_MONTH
    tstStack <- stack(mrlist[grep(paste0(y,"_",sprintf("%02d", m)), names(mrlist))] )
    tstList[[i]] <- tstStack
    i <- i+1  
  } 
}

#3. extract the min raster(s)
min.rlist <- list()
for (i in 1:length(tstList)) {
  min.rlist[[i]] <- min(tstList[[i]])
  print(i) # to track the process
}
```

Comment: this works for me. thanks. Can it be reduced to less number of lines?

Comment: You have already the short version as the second answer (the better one in my idea).